# Uncountability of Real numbers - fault in counter proof

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, cardinals

I came up with the below proof for the proposition “the set of real numbers is countable”. Can you please help me find the error in this proof.

Proof:

1. Let P be the set of primes. P is a subset of integers and hence it is countable. Also P is not finite.
2. Let real numbers be defined as
   $r = x.d_1 .d_2 .d_3 .\ldots. $
   Let L be the set
   $\{x, d_1, d_2, d_3, \ldots\}. $
   L is countable. [If L is not countable, L is a counter-example to the Continuum hypothesis as cardinality of real numbers is exponential to cardinality of L. ( [Ref 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) )]
3. We could map the set L to set P as:

   $x   => p_1$

   $d_1 => p_2$

   $d_2 => p_3$

   $\vdots$
4. Each real number can then be represented as:
   $p_1^x.p_2 ^{d_1}.p_3^{d_2} .\ldots. $
5. Thus real numbers are countable. (This technique is an extension of [Ref 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set#Some_technical_details) - Proposition: The Cartesian product of two countable sets A and B is countable.)

References:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set#Some_technical_details

Comment: What does "Let $L$ be the set $\{x,d_1,d_2,d_3,\cdots \}$" mean?  If you just mean the set of all sequences of digits (or something close to that) then it is obviously uncountable.

Comment: You are using $x,d_1,d_2,...$ as if they were constants, whereas in fact they are free variables in your definition of real numbers as decimal expansions: $x$ is a free variable varying over the integers; and $d_1,d_2,...$ are free variables varying over the decimal digits $\{0,1,2,...,9\}$. A proof which confuses free variables and constants is invalid.

Comment: Technically, a _set_ (such as $\{x,d_1,d_2,d_3,\ldots \}$) is not a _sequence._ An object such as the number $3$ can be at most one element of a set; conventionally, we are allowed to write it more than once when listing the elements but it still counts only once. So $\{3,3,1,3\}$ is the exact same set as $\{1,3\}.$ Since the $d_i$ in $\{x,d_1,d_2,d_3,\ldots \}$ are all chosen from the digits $0$ through $9,$ not only is that set countable, its size cannot be greater than $11$ (that is, it consists of at most the ten digits and the possibly larger integer $x$).

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos for the suggestion. I was lost in the <sup><sub> tag sea and and made a mistake.

Comment: I just updated point 4 - Sould be primes raised to the digits not the other way around.

Comment: you main problem is the infinite product of numbers is not an actual integer number. So your mapping doesn't map to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What I am *really* confused about, is how is $L$ going to be a counterexample to CH if it is not countable.

Comment: That make sense. He states that $L$ is not countable and $2^L = \aleph_1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's patch up the technical error at the beginning of your argument by referring to the *sequence* $L = x,d_1,d_2,d_3,\ldots .$
There is then indeed a one-to-one correspondence between the sequence $L$
and the set of all primes.

Now let's consider the real number $\frac{10}9.$
In this example, $x = 1$ and $d_i = 1$ for all $i.$
Then you claim to represent $\frac{10}9$ by
$$ p_1^x \cdot p_2^{d_1} \cdot p_3^{d_2} \cdot p_4^{d_3} \cdots
= 2^1 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1 \cdot 7^1 \cdot 11^1 \cdots 
= 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11 \cdots.$$

But what is $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11 \cdots$?
If we take any *finite* product of primes, such as
$2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11 \cdots 2017,$ we get a positive integer,
but $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11 \cdots$ is not a finite product.
It's the product of *all* of the prime numbers.
The "$\cdots$" part means we just keep multiplying and multiplying without
end, and the partial products keep getting bigger and bigger.
Consider any integer $n$; since every partial product is an integer and the partial products never stop getting bigger, eventually they get bigger than $n.$ Hence the product
$2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11 \cdots$  cannot be an integer.

What you *can* show with this technique is the well-known fact that the set of *terminating* decimals is countable.
Any terminating decimal has a last non-zero digit and therefore there is a last positive power of a prime in the product;
all the factors after that are $1,$ and the partial products after that point are all the same.
Hence for a *terminating* decimal $x.d_1d_2d_3\cdots,$ we find that
$p_1^x \cdot p_2^{d_1} \cdot p_3^{d_2} \cdot p_4^{d_3} \cdots$ 
is an integer, giving us an injection from the set of terminating
decimals to the set of integers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder if there is an already studied 'extension' to integers which deals with this class of numbers. Are you aware of any?

Comment: @NiKS001 You may be interested in the [$p$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Cardinality).